# iPhone 6 Plus Camera Performance Using AVCaptureStillImageOutput.CaptureStillImageAsynchronously Is Abysmal, Why?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, avfoundation, ios-camera

We have been using AVCaptureStillImageOutput.CaptureStillImageAsynchronously to capture on image on iOS in our application.  On iPhone 5, 5c, 5s, and 6 this call takes about 300-400ms to return using the AVCaptureSession.PresetPhoto setting.  On iPhone 6 Plus, this takes 800-1250ms.  This camera problem only exists on the iPhone 6 Plus.

Why?  We have looked at the settings and are unclear if there is something we are doing wrong.

We are also using the following pixel format:  CVPixelFormatType.CV48RGB

Answer (score 0):

The key difference between iPhone 6 Plus and the others is the OIS (optical image stabilisation). And a key feature of OIS is that it takes time to do its thing.

Consequently, given an `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` called `stillImageOutput`, you can add this to your setup in order to speed things up (although, obviously, you lose the image stabilisation...):

```
if (stillImageOutput.stillImageStabilizationSupported)
  stillImageOutput.automaticallyEnablesStillImageStabilizationWhenAvailable = FALSE;
```